# What is the reason helper classes' methods are declared as static?

Tags: java, class, static, helper

Why are all the helper classes or utility classes being declared as static?

Is it only for easyness by not creating the instanceof class everytime?

Would static hit the performace badly?

For example:

```
DateHelper.getCurrentDate();
```

Comment: One reason: Because they're state-less.

Comment: And static doesn't affect performance harmfully, au contraire. Since you don't need to create an instance, it's more efficient.

Comment: Static does not make a performance difference in general. In specific situations it can matter a lot.

Comment: __Not really__. See how `GSON`, on the other hand, requires you to construct `new GSON()` objects for use. There's also `ScriptManager` which uses non-static methods.

Comment: @Kayaman that is a very dangerous statement. Instances will still need to be made when the class is initialized. And e.g. a singleton with large memory footprint that isn't used anymore after a certain point actually degrades performance.

Comment: Its more of a *design* thing.. As Hovercroft points out, there is no need to keep the *state* here.

Comment: ^ 1. See `Math.random()` constructs a `new Random()` for `private static Random randomNumberGenerator`. 2. ??? 3. Profit!

Comment: @dtech Well I wasn't talking about singletons. It's true that the class instance will need to be created (for any classes), but using `new MyHelper.someMethod()` instead of `MyHelper.someMethod()` would be a worse solution (for several reasons). But you're right in that static is not something that you should be using just for performance reasons.

Comment: @Kayaman You literally said "And static doesn't affect performance harmfully, au contraire". There are many instances where `static` hurts performance (and many were it helps performance)

Comment: @dtech - I'm trying to recall, from my 10 years of working inside a JVM, a situation where making a method static made it less efficient.

Comment: Yes, I'd appreciate if @dtech elaborated a bit on this, since he seems to know many instances where static hurts performance. Preferably something that doesn't involve a design flaw (such as the singleton with a long living static instance). Give me an example where a static method performs worse than a non-static one. Or are you just arguing about my wording?

Comment: @HotLicks `static` can also apply to attributes, then it can become dangerous. I think you're right about that making a *method* static will not hurt performance, but that doesn't mean making *something* static won't hurt performance. Your statement that "static won't hurt performance" was too general.

Comment: @Unihedron - ??? A static method is not "inner", and is loaded and verified exactly like an instance method.

Comment: @dtech - I didn't say "static won't hurt performance", and the person who did was clearly saying it in a context where the term was meant to apply to methods.  (And how do you apply `static` to an "attribute"?)

Comment: @HotLicks How is "static won't hurt performance" different from "static doesn't affect performance harmfully" then? And to apply static to a field/attribute... Put static in its declaration `public static int myField = 5;`

Comment: @dtech - Just a little hint:  After each comment is the ID of the person commenting.  And where in the JLS is the term "attribute" defined?

Comment: @HotLicks excuse me, I meant to react to Kayaman. Attribute is [a common synonym for field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350423/terminology-of-class-attribute-vs-member-vs-variable-vs-field).

Comment: So you're nit-picking others' terminology but want leeway with yours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they are not confined to state, they have a single functionality that is purely stateless. For example `Math.abs(double a)` , it takes a double argument and returns the absolute value. As simple as that. So you dont have to do for example something like

```
Math m=new Math();
m.abs(12.33);
```

each time to do a simple absolute value calculation which depends only on its argument, using static imposes a simplicity to calling utility methods.

Edit:- Want to add that there is no performance hit in using static methods. There would only be a lag if the method is `static synchronized` and mutiple threads want to access it simultaneuously, vs accessing same method (in non static context) in different instances by threads. But most utility methods are atomic in functionality so making them synchronized does not make sense.

Answer (score -1):

To not to create their instances. Also you can make them follow [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: No problems. It will never happen again